# Delete an element from an Array based on a condition block and return that element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a quick Ruby or Rails method to delete an element from an Array based on a condition provided in a block and then return that element?

Let's say, given:

```
e1.good? # false
e2.good? # true
e3.good? # true
a = [e1, e2, e3]
```

Is there a method delete_and_return_if doing this:

```
a.delete_and_return_if { |e| e.good? }      # delete e2 from a and returns e2
[e1].delete_and_return_if { |e| e.good? }   # returns nil
```

Or at least is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have duplicates or that you want to delete all same elements, you can do

```
a.delete(a.detect(&:good?))
```

- `a.detect(&:good?)` will return the first `good?` object or `nil` if
  there is none.
- `a.delete(elem)` will delete and return your element.

Or if you have duplicates and only want to delete the first one:

```
a.delete(a.index(a.detect(&:good?)))
```

Comment: So I guess this is the cleanest solution we have in Ruby? One thing that is not so perfect is that it has to take two iterations :)

Comment: @Innerpeacer You could do `return a.clone - a.delete_if(&:good?)` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is delete_if, this is a Ruby function. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html

Comment: Unfortunately, delete_if return the array itself, not the element being deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
 a = [e1, e2, e3]

 a.delete_if{|e|!e.good?}

 it will delete e1. and returns e2 and e3
```

Answer (score 1):

This will update array and return deleted entry:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

p a
# => [1, 2, 3]

deleted = a.delete a.detect {|e| e == 2 }
p deleted
# => 2

p a
# => [1, 3]
```

so you can do like this:

```
a.delete a.detect(&:good?)
```

**UPDATE:** thanks to @oldergod for recalling me about `detect`